# removing leaves doesn't affect a BST - C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-search-tree

I wrote a function to nullify all the leaves of a BST. The BST has a left and right pointer of course and a char called data to store the value of the node.

```
void removeLeaves(struct Tree* T){
  if(T->left == NULL && T->right == NULL){
    printf("removing %c\n", T->data);
    T=NULL;
  }
  else{
    if(T->left!=NULL){
      removeLeaves(T->left);
    }
    if(T->right!=NULL){  
      removeLeaves(T->right);
    }
  }  
}
```

I Print the tree before and after envoking this function.
And although the print statement above works and prints the nodes that are nullified, the resulting tree is the same.
I have something like:

```
print(BST);
removeLeaves(BST);
print(BST);
```

Any idea what's going on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T=NULL;` assigns null to a local pointer, not to anything in your tree. You need to use a `struct Tree **` so that you can modify the `struct Tree *`:

```
void removeLeaves(struct Tree ** T){
  if((*T)->left == NULL && (*T)->right == NULL){
    printf("removing %c\n", (*T)->data);
    *T = NULL;
  }
  else{
    if((*T)->left!=NULL){
      pruneTree((*T)->left);
    }
    if((*T)->right!=NULL){  
      pruneTree((*T)->right);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Why `struct Tree ** T`? Why not just `*T = NULL` wouldn't work?

I assume when we have `struct Tree* T`, T would be pointer to a tree. So we just dereference it and set it to null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I get error: passing argument 1 of ‘removeLeaves’ from incompatible pointer type in removeLeaves((*T)->left);

Comment: @MinaHany You now need to pass in a pointer to that element: removeLeaves(&(*T)->left);

Answer (score 1):

You are passing T by value, so setting T to null does nothing (T is just a local copy of the pointer).

You need some way of setting T's 'owner' (i.e. parent->left or parent->right) to null.

(Also by setting T to null you risk a memory leak - do you need to free()?)

Comment: I knew I had problems with the pointers somewhere! Thanks a lot :)
Yeah, I do need to free but I'm just leaving it out for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have the parts you need.  It's mostly a matter of reordering them.

```
void removeLeaves(struct Tree* const T){
  if(T->left!=NULL){
    removeLeaves(T->left);
    T->left = NULL;
  }
  if(T->right!=NULL){  
    removeLeaves(T->right);
    T->right = NULL;
  }
}
```

Note however the `const`.  Your code can work without it, but it shouldn't, because setting `T = NULL` doesn't actually do anything, although one might thing that it would.

*Update:*  @PaulP.R.O.'s answer is interesting, incidentally.  I prefer mine, but you can try both and see which suits.

By the way, be sure that you don't need a call to `free()` in there somewhere, to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: actually this would remove all the leaves and only the root node would be remaining at the end :)
Yeah, I do have to free() but I'm leaving it out for now.

Comment: I misunderstood.  I thought that you wanted only the root node to remain.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: I read my question and I see why you misunderstood. My bad, it is very misleading.